# Run gsap after apollo query

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo, gsap

I am building an SSR page with Apollo and NUXT... I have added now GSAP to add some animations but I am struggling to refresh GSAP ScrollTrigger.

I have 2 big problems:

1. When I navigate to a different page and then return to the one where gsap effects are happening, the gsap is not being refreshed and the animation fail.
2. If I refresh the browser in a different page (within my app) and then return to the one where the gsap happen, now apollo fetch again from the server and gsap can not find the elements required to run the animation...

Can someone guide me in the correct way so my events are triggered in the order I need?

this is the part of my code that works if I do not navigate anywhere:

```
...
methods: {
    gsap() {
      this.$ScrollTrigger.refresh();
      const sections = this.$gsap.utils.toArray("section");
      let maxWidth = 0;

      const getMaxWidth = () => {
        maxWidth = 0;
        sections.forEach((section) => {
          maxWidth += section.offsetWidth;
        });
      };
      getMaxWidth();
      this.$ScrollTrigger.addEventListener("refreshInit", getMaxWidth);

      this.$gsap.to(sections, {
        x: () => `-${maxWidth - window.innerWidth}`,
        ease: "none",
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".wrapper",
          pin: true,
          scrub: 2,
          end: () => `+=${maxWidth}`,
          invalidateOnRefresh: true
        }
      });

      sections.forEach((sct, i) => {
        this.$ScrollTrigger.create({
          trigger: sct,
          start: () => 'top top-=' + (sct.offsetLeft - window.innerWidth/2) * (maxWidth / (maxWidth - window.innerWidth)),
          end: () => '+=' + sct.offsetWidth * (maxWidth / (maxWidth - window.innerWidth)),
          toggleClass: { targets: sct, className: "active" },
          onUpdate() {
            //ScrollTrigger.refresh();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.gsap();
    });
  },
...
```

Comment: There is no way of using `template $refs`? Maybe it's coming from the fact that it cannot find the element properly. Also, why do you need `nextTick` here? At the end, you probably want to trigger your animation once the elements are fetched (rather than in `mounted()`). A [repro] may be nice here.

Comment: @kissu you are right, the error (2) happen because it can not find the element... basically the element is a loop generated after apolo load the data... the error 1 can be fixed with a resize simulation but believe it or not can not find a solution for nuxt yet

Comment: you need `.create()` ScrollTrigger after elements was loaded. After elements was deleted you need to `.kill()` ScrollTrigger and recreated it after they loaded again. If your elements exist but changed width, height or position on the page you need to `.refresh()` ScrollTrigger. For find your ScrollTrigger you can use variable or `.getById()` `.getAll()`, methods